# Comparing pairs of rows in a list of data frames

Tags: r

I have a list that's 1314 element long. Each element is a data frame consisting of two rows and four columns.

```
Game.ID         Team   Points    Victory
1 201210300CLE  CLE     94       0
2 201210300CLE  WAS     84       0
```

I would like to use the lapply function to compare points for each team in each game, and change Victory to 1 for the winning team.

I'm trying to use this function:

```
test_vic <- lapply(all_games, function(x) {if (x[1,3] > x[2,3]) {x[1,4] = 1}})
```

But the result it produces is a list 1314 elements long with just the Game ID and either a 1 or a null, a la:

```
$`201306200MIA`
[1] 1

$`201306160SAS`
NULL
```

How can I fix my code so that each data frame maintains its shape. (I'm guessing solving the null part involves if-else, but I need to figure out the right syntax.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
all_games %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  group_by(Game.ID) %>%
  mutate(Victory = row_number(Points)-1)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
#Groups: Game.ID
#
#       Game.ID Team Points Victory
#1 201210300CLE  CLE     94       1
#2 201210300CLE  WAS     84       0
#3 201210300CME  CLE     90       0
#4 201210300CME  WAS     92       1
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer Steven. Could you say a little bit more about how row_number is working in this case? From reading the documentation, I see that row_number gives a rank. How is it evaluating which points total is higher?

Comment: @CharlieMintz `row_number()` gives a rank in ascending order. Since you only have two entries, it gives 1 to the lowest `Points` and 2 to the highest `Points`. When we substract 1, we get 0 and 1

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
lapply(all_games, function(x) {x$Victory[which.max(x$Points)] <- 1; x})
```

Or another option would be to convert the `list` to `data.table` by using `rbindlist` and then do the conversion

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(all_games)[,Victory:= +(Points==max(Points)) ,Game.ID][]
```

#### data

```
 all_games <- list(structure(list(Game.ID = c("201210300CLE", 
 "201210300CLE"
 ), Team = c("CLE", "WAS"), Points = c(94L, 84L), Victory = c(0L, 
 0L)), .Names = c("Game.ID", "Team", "Points", "Victory"),
 class =  "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2")), structure(list(Game.ID = c("201210300CME", "201210300CME"
 ), Team = c("CLE", "WAS"), Points = c(90, 92), Victory = c(0L, 
 0L)), .Names = c("Game.ID", "Team", "Points", "Victory"),
 row.names = c("1", "2"), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. This is helpful.